# How can I manage UILabel's position when rotating the device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitoolbar

I'm using storyboard.

And I have a toolbar with toolbarButtonItems separated by flexible spaces.

I want labels for each buttons. So I put labels in storyboard, but when rotating the device to landscape, labels are not aligned with buttons.

How can I solve this?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Kindest regards,

Comment: are you not using auto layout?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Xcode, so I don't know about auto layout...

Comment: Check out answer by @theMonster, he has provided you links with different options.

Comment: @BhaveshNai: [inline code spans should not be used for emphasis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right/165710#165710).

Answer (score 2):

Well good sir, like many before you, you're presented with a two options.

1. Use [Auto-Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)'s Constraint system to describe what you want.
2. Use [-layoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews), and manually reposition the views in your ViewController.

The Second document on is on how to subclass UIView's in general. Defiantly worth the read. Since you said you're a beginner, it's probably best to use Auto-Layout, so you should probably start there.

Comment: Thank you theMonster. I understand what Auto Layout is.

But I have no idea to add constraints when in landscape mode as I want labels aligned with barButtonItems.

Comment: @MasaruKitajima then you don't know what auto-layout is. Because what you're wanting is exactly what auto layout is for

Comment: Understand. I'll try to read the documents deeply. I added constraints to UILables, but they are related with other UILabels. And I can't find the way to add constraints to barButtonItems yet.